# chef-shell as chef-client in chef-zero mode (local mode)

Tags: chef, chef-zero

Can I run `chef-shell` as chef-client when my chef-client is running in chef-zero (chef-local) mode?

The parameter used to run `chef-client` in zero mode is `-z`. However using `-z` with `chef-shell` just makes it run in chef-client mode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start chef-zero as it's own process, and then point chef-shell's server config at the running chef-zero.

See this example:

In one terminal:

```
$ chef-zero
>> Starting Chef Zero (v4.2.1)...
>> WEBrick (v1.3.1) on Rack (v1.6.1) is listening at http://127.0.0.1:8889
>> Press CTRL+C to stop
```

In another terminal:

```
$ chef-shell -z -S http://localhost:8889
```

You could also create a new `client.rb` file and use: `chef-shell -z -c /path/to/client.rb`

Answer (score 0):

Mike's answer is correct.

When doing this on test-kitchen nodes I use the following "script" which also populates the chef-zero with the necessary cookbooks, etc.

```
/opt/chef/bin/chef-zero -d
cd /tmp/kitchen
knife upload . -c client.rb
knife upload . -c client.rb  # because the first one sometimes fails
chef-shell -z -c client.rb
```

I've created a [feature request](https://feedback.chef.io/forums/301644-chef-product-feedback/suggestions/10297551-local-mode-z-support-for-chef-shell-equivalent) for simplifying this which you may wish to [vote for](https://feedback.chef.io/forums/301644-chef-product-feedback/suggestions/10297551-local-mode-z-support-for-chef-shell-equivalent).